# Python fill array with 0's without numpy

Tags: python

I know in python you can fill an array with 0's using `numpy.zeroes(size)` but as part of learning I am asked to not use `numpy`, so my question is, is there a way to fill an array without `numpy.zeroes` function?

specificly How do I fill the following list with 0's in the following functions?

```
def myHistWithRescale(listOfNums, maxInt):
    """Givne a list of real numbers in any range, first scale the numbers to
    inters between 0 and maxInt (inclusive), then return the number of occurrences
    of each integer in a list
    """
    rescaledData = rescaleToInt(listOfNums, maxInt)  
    return counts
```

Comment: The title doesn't seem to match the comment in the method.

Comment: How is that function relevant to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the function, you can do: `arr = [0] * maxInt`. Where `maxInt` is the size  of list.
Similarly if you want to fill an array with something other than 0; you can just replace the 0 with any number you want to fill

Answer (score 3):

To create a list of size `n` of all zeros, just write `[0] * n`